# simple server in linux

Tags: linux, network-programming

i am a new linux user and i am trying to connet to the internet via my mobile subscription (blackberry)    on my previous windows installation all i do is run a simple server program which executes the contents of a .ini file and change my proxy settings to 127.0.0.1:8080

please is there any way to make such a program or script on linux....    i would really appreciate any help with that.   thanks  :)

i have attached a photo of it here to clarify my question....  [photo](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9_HleXTGu6ySExlYWo5ODdNemc&authuser=0)

the windows executable of the program is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9_HleXTGu6yfnJ4Z3JJOGhjN1VWS3ltV3Q5cWpuQ0ptVTRzTnNlS2tRR1RNRnRnem9vdE0&authuser=0)

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you are trying to do. Are you trying to send packets from your Blackberry to this Linux server which would act as a proxy?

Comment: trying to route all connections on my machine through the proxy server

Comment: so doesn't matter it is a Blackberry, you should use iptables

Comment: @rodolk i dont think that addresses my question..........      the attached photo should explain better

Comment: I really cannot understand the photo. 1-Do you have a diagram of all components? There is your machine from where I suppose connections are created. Then the proxy server, is it in the same PC? 2-And you are trying to route all HTTP connections from that PC through the proxy server. Is this correct? 3-Is it a problem of just configuring a proxy server?

Comment: yes yes yes exactly......         same pc    just trying to route all HTTP connections through the server .   The configuration is my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood your question well.
You need to set environment variables http_proxy and https_proxy

```
export http_proxy="http://proxy-server:port"
export https_proxy="https://proxy-server:port"
```

Here's a link where you can read more, http://www.shellhacks.com/en/HowTo-Use-a-Proxy-on-the-Linux-Command-Line , but there are lots of sites with info.